# Hibernate IN clause over multiple attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a table `user_activities` with columns, `user_id`, `activity_id` and `comments`. `activity_id` and `user_id` are both foreign keys, with the activity table having another attribute `activity_name`. To fetch a row, with a specific `user_id` and `activity_name` I can use:

```
FROM UserActivityMapping AS mapping
    INNER JOIN mapping.activityId AS activity
    WHERE userId = <something> AND activity.activityName = <something>
```

So far, so good. Now, given a list of `Pair`s of `<UserId, ActivityName>`, I want to delete all such rows. This list could be quite big.. like 600-700 items big. For now it looks like on big mess of a query I can generate:

```
DELETE ...
    WHERE (userId = userId[0] AND activity.activityName = activityName[0]) OR
          (userId = userId[1] AND activity.activityName = activityName[1]) OR
          ...
```

Which clearly is not the best approach here. How do I go about this? Something like this would be amazing:

```
"WHERE (userId, activityId) in :userActivityList".setParameterList(
    new List<Pair<String, String>>()
);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [rant]Questions like this shows how crappy our tools are.[/rant]

Comment: @biziclop: :( Not what I was looking for...

Comment: Please check this example , in this mapping is done between two different package class.. it may help you   http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4/hibernate_xml_mapping.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar issue before and wrote a fairly simple function to build the hql dynamically

```
private String buildInClause(List<Integer> keys)  {
   String inClause = "object.id in (";
   for (Integer key : keys) {
     inClause += key + ',";
   }
   inClause = inClause.substring(0,inClause.length -1) + ")";  // strip off last comma and add a closing paren.
   return inClause;
}
```

for your problem you can slightly modify this approach

```
inClause = " userId || '-' || activity.activityName in (";

// loop over your pairs however they are passed in
inClause += "'" + userId + "-" + activityName + "',";
// strip off trailing coman and add closing paren
inClause = inClause.substring(0,inClause.length -1) + ")";  
// end loop
```